# Why can't you put multiple selectors in this jQuery code?

Tags: jquery

Seems easy enough, you click .nextbutton to open the #contact division and you'd think if you put '#contact,.nextbutton' you could use both to close it but that doesn't work?
I was wondering why.

```
$('.nextbutton').click(function () {
$('#contact').stop().fadeTo(1500, 1);
});

$('#contact').click(function () {
$('#contact').stop().fadeTo(1500, 0.001);
});
```

Comment: Why don't you give an example of the syntax you are attempting?

Comment: $('#contact, .nextbutton') should definitely work.

Comment: Your sample could use some HTML so we could see why it might not be working

Comment: Works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/wqUQA/

Comment: Sorry... here is an example.  http://jsfiddle.net/jX7Df/ Try adding the .nextbutton.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#contact, .nextbutton').click(function () {
            $('#contact').stop().fadeTo(1500, ($(this).hasClass('nextbutton') ? 1 : 0.001));
  });​
```